# Laravel Dropdown Form Get Form Database

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.4 . I am trying to get data form Department table and data come also the problem there more dropdown menu come also please tell how can i solve this problem. Thanks advance.[

```html
<div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('department','Department')}}
     @foreach($department as $value)
      {{Form::select('department',[$value->name], ' ', array('placeholder' => 'Select Department','class'=>'form-control'))}}
     @endforeach

 </div>
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're after. Your current code seems to output several select boxes, one for each department and my best guess is that you want to output only one select box, with each department as an option in it. You can achieve that by doing something like this (You may have to adapt this code slightly to suit your needs):

**The manual approach**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="department">Department</label>
    <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Department</option>
        @foreach ($departments as $department)
            <option value="{{ $department->id }}">{{ $department->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

**Using Laravel Collective's Form Builder**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('department', 'Department') !!}
    {!! Form::select('department', ['' => 'Select Department'] + $departments->pluck'name', 'id')) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: What's the difference between this two approach ?
In what situation it's more benefical to implement one and not the other ?

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. @MarouaneSihad I think it just comes down to personal preference. The Laravel Collective Form Builder packages makes it easy to generate form components without having to manually output any HTML, it also helps with pre-selecting and pre-filling components as well. However, it can be quite easily done manually too

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this way :-

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{Form::label('department','Department')}}
  <select class="form-control" name="department">
    @foreach($department as $value)
      <option value="$value">$value</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion I can do this way and I want to do another way but my problem is solve.I am use    $department = Departments::pluck('name');
  <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('department','Department')}}

                                 {{Form::select('department', $department , ' ', array('placeholder' => 'Select Department','class'=>'form-control'))}}
                        
                    </div>